# Stop the current getJSON request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I have a function who call a getJSON. But the getJSON call is often not finish when the function is call again.

So I want to stop the previous getJSON still running before send the new one.

I try to save my getJSON call in a global variable and call abort() in the beginning of my function, but I got an error

```
TypeError: vr is undefined
```

Here is my function

```
var vr;

function getVol() {
    vr.abort();

    var data = {
        form : fields
    };

    vr = $.getJSON('getVol.php', data).done(function(r) {

        $.each( r, function( key, item ) {
            $.each( item, function( key, value ) {
                if(parseInt(value) > maxValue) maxValue = parseInt(value);
            });
        });

    }).fail(function() {
        console.log( "error" );
    });
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why not the other way around? Prevent when a getJSON is still running?

Comment: is the same data being requested or would it be a different more updated set of data and thats why you want to refire the request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting an error because when you call the function the first time, `vr` is empty. You need to check that it's set first.

```
function getVol() {
    if (vr) {
        vr.abort();
    }
    // rest of function
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `if(vr === undefined) { vr.abort(); }` ?

Comment: @ruzel Why? No valid value of `vr` will be falsey,